# using sql server insert statement in C# programe

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

hello everyone i was trying to insert values obtained from my front end to sql server database.here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Geocoding.Google;
using Geocoding;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class regforswa : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lat;
        string longi;
        IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder() { };
        Address[] addresses = 
        geocoder.Geocode(TextBox4.Text+TextBox5.Text+TextBox6.Text).ToArray();
        foreach (Address adrs in addresses)
        {
           //Response.Write("lat=" +adrs.Coordinates.Latitude.ToString());
            //Response.Write( "longi="+ adrs.Coordinates.Longitude.ToString());
        }
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=swa1;User Id=swa1;Password=swa1;");//datasource=localhost name,initial catalog=db name
        //integrated security=windiws authentication OR for sql authentication specify
        //userid and password 
        conn.Open();//opens connection with the database
        try
        {//exeption handling

            String uname=TextBox1.Text;
            String pwd=TextBox3.Text;
            String mnumber = TextBox7.Text;
            String sques = DropDownList1.Text;
            String res = TextBox8.Text;
            String adress = TextBox4.Text;
            String cty = TextBox5.Text;
            String zpcode = TextBox6.Text;
           // Response.Write("uname"+uname +"pwd"+ pwd);
            SqlCommand newcomm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO regforswa(username,password,mno,sq,response,address,city,zipcode) VALUES (uname,pwd,mnumber,sques,res,adress,cty,zpcode)", conn);
            if (newcomm.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {            
                result.Visible = true;
                result.Text = "entered successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                result.Text = "not entered";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

but i am getting this error

> Invalid column name 'uname'. Invalid column name 'pwd'. Invalid column
>   name 'mnumber'. Invalid column name 'sques'. Invalid column name
>   'res'. Invalid column name 'adress'. Invalid column name 'cty'.
>   Invalid column name 'zpcode'.

I checked my database column names and it is perfect. please somebody help.why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the INSERT command you cannot pass directly the variables values in that way. You use a parameter placeholder, then you build the parameter collection of your command

```
    string uname=TextBox1.Text;
    string pwd=TextBox3.Text;
    string mnumber = TextBox7.Text;
    string sques = DropDownList1.Text;
    string res = TextBox8.Text;
    string adress = TextBox4.Text;
    string cty = TextBox5.Text;
    string zpcode = TextBox6.Text;
    SqlCommand newcomm = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO regforswa
             (username,password,mno,sq,response,address,city,zipcode) VALUES  
             (@uname,@pwd,@mnumber,@sques,@res,@adress,@cty,@zpcode)", conn);
     newcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", uname);
     ..... and so on for the other parmaters required by the placeholders

     if (newcomm.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
```

Also, keep in mind that the parameters should be typed exactly how your fields requires. For example, if the field mno is of type integer then you need to convert the value for that parameter

```
     newcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mnumber", Convert.ToInt32(mnumber));
```